# Can you buy Intel CPUs without the integrated GPU?

Tags: intel-graphics

I have a issue with Intel adding a GPU to their CPUs. I don't want their GPU and I certainly dont want to pay for it. Is there any vendor that sells CPUs without a GPU in it or do I have to accept that Intel will shove their GPU down my throat?

Comment: You have to realise that you are in the minority of users who do not use IGP. Most offices and home users use IGP and only power users or gamers have a dedicated GPU. Plus you mention you don't want to pay for the IGP but if intel made two of every CPU one with and one without could you imagine the spike in costings to double their manufacturing process...

Comment: Sure - You'll need to do a bit of research but the Xeon E3 series *may* be usable on the same 'family' of processors, and there's models without GPUs in some cases. Likewise the AMD FX series (which is their 'higher' end processors) have no onboard GPU.

Comment: Adding to the previous comments, you may well be able to buy a processor without IGP, but because of production quantities you are unlikely to save money by doing so.

Answer (score 5):

Lets analyse your question:

1. I don't want their GPU and
2. I certainly dont want to pay for it.
3. uhm, vendors?

Why do you care about point 1? If you buy a CPU with an on die GPU just do not use the GPU part.

As fort paying for it. Creating a separate die with only the CPU part will increase costs. It is likely cheaper to simply build one design. So may may actually pay less for the same CPU if it ship with a GPU on the same die. And once more, nobody forces you to use that part.

Now there is a downside. That GPU takes up quite a lot space on the chip. That space could have been used for a larger CPU (e.g. one with more cores).  Intel actually does make these, look at the Xeon range.

3) Vendors: Vendors do not make Intel CPUs. They sell things.  Intel makes Intel CPUs... (That is assume that with Intel CPUs you mean Intel CPU's, and not x86(tm) CPU from firms as AMD, Cyrix, VIA, Intel, ...)

If these vendors have a product which sells well they will buy and sell it. If they need to stock up on relative rare CPUs which do not sell as well to their **average customer** then most simply will balance that risk vs extra profit.

Answer (score 1):

There still are some Intel CPUs without the integrated GPU. Use http://ark.intel.com/ for details.